# Can two irreducible polynomials have different powers of the same real number as roots?

Tags: irreducible-polynomials

Say we have two irreducible polynomials in $Q [x] $. We call them $f, g$. Say one of the roots of $f $ is $a$. Is it possible that $g$ satisfies a root of the form $a^n$ for some natural number $n $?

Thanks

Comment: Sure: take $g$ to be the minimal polynomial of $a^n$.

Answer (score 3):

Take $f(x)=x-a$ and for a fixed naturel number $n,$   $g(x)=x-a^n.$ The two polynomials are irreducibles in $Q[x]$ and the root of $f$ is $a$ and for $g$ is $a^n.$

Comment: Could you kindly give examples of polynomials that are not linear? Thanks!

Comment: These polynomials are not linears

Comment: They are. They are of degree 1,  right?

Comment: Yes but as i know a linear polynomial is of the form $\alpha x.$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Take a root of the form $A\sqrt\alpha+B\sqrt\beta$, where both *a* and *b* are square-free. For instance, for $A=B=1$, $\alpha=2$, $\beta=3$, and $n=2$, we have $x^2-10x+1$ and $x^4-10x^2+1$.